# NFluent: fluently check a property of an exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nfluent

I have a function that is supposed to raise an exception `FooException`. This exception has a list of items stored in one of its properties `AffectedElements`. How can I perform tests against this list? For example:

```
Check.ThatCode(() => somefunction("qux", 1, null))
     .Throws<FooException>()
     .«WhatDoIPutHere»
     .IsInAscendingOrder();
```

Answer (score 4):

As of now, there is no way to extract a field/property from an exception to check it.
The best you can do is use **WithProperty** which only support equality check:

```
Check.ThatCode(() => somefunction("qux", 1, null))
 .Throws<FooException>()
 .WithProperty("propName", expectedValue);
```

**Update**:
The latest version of NFluent offers a feature for that.
see the [wiki](https://github.com/tpierrain/NFluent/wiki/Check.ThatCode#whichmemberpropertyexpression-v27)